# Scope of cached RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was wondering what is the scope of a cached RDD. For example:

```
// Cache an RDD.
rdd.cache
// Pass the RDD to a method of another class.
otherClass.calculate(rdd) // This method performs various actions.
// Pass the RDD to a method of the same class.
calculate(rdd)            // This method also performs some actions.
// Perform an action in the same method where the RDD was cached.
rdd.count
```

In the example above, will the RDD be materialized once? (It won't have to be recreated?) What is the scope of caching?

And should I always unpersist the RDD after I used it, if I don't need it anymore?

Comment: 1. It will be computed once, 2. It takes resources so it makes sense to unpersist

Comment: Thank you very much and just to be clear if I had not used the cache method, it would be recomputed every time I used an action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether an RDD is cached or not is part of the mutable state of the RDD object. If you call `rdd.cache` it will be marked for caching from then on. It does not matter what scope you access it from.

As to whether you should unpersist the RDD: The RDD will be unpersisted automatically if it is garbage collected. It is for you to decide whether this is soon in enough. The cache takes up space on the *executors*, while the automatic cleanup happens in response to memory pressure on the *driver*.